# EXTJS - Cannot set value in record in GridColumn renderer

Tags: extjs, renderer

I am trying to implement the 'Sum' feature on a grid panel. The fields that are to be summed are calculated dynamically. I tried setting the record inside the renderer. It seems to be working but i see this exception in developer tools.

```
Cannot read property 'attributes' of null
```

Reason i think the underlying record is not changed even though the renderer changes the display with its return.

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2d2r 
Line: 192

To reproduce, please click "increase" in the "Increase or Decrease" dropdown.

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using an editor dropdown to do that? That's an awful UI.

Comment: What would you recommend instead ?

Comment: Anything else: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2d55

Comment: @Evan By the way, rec.commit() worked for my original question. But i want to know more details on your comment about the UI. This  is the requirement from the business but if you have a better idea, it would help. Thanks.

Comment: It's just a clunky UI, I don't see why you would use cell editing to do that.

Comment: Gotcha.. Thanks for your input